# TailwindCSS: disabled variant not working

Tags: tailwind-css

I am trying to use *disabled* variant in tailiwnd, but it does not seem to work. I do not know what to do.

I want to change button apperance if it is disabled, I have read the documentation and it says 'disabled' variant in not enabled by default. So I modify my tailwind.config.js and now it looks like this:

```js
module.exports = {
  purge: [],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  variants: {
    extend: {
      opacity: ['disabled']
    }
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

I have this code in my page, both buttons look the same:

```html
  <div class="text-center space-x-8">
    <button type="button" class="py-2 px-4 bg-green-500 text-white font-semibold rounded-lg shadow-md hover:bg-green-700 focus:outline-none disabled:opacity-50" tabindex="-1">
      Submit
    </button>
    <button type="button" class="py-2 px-4 bg-green-500 text-white font-semibold rounded-lg shadow-md disabled:opacity-50" disabled tabindex="-1">
      Submit
    </button>
  </div>
```

I already re-compiled my code and deleted all my browsers caché, but it still does not work. Do I have to do anything else for this to work?

Comment: This is because the configuration file is not being loaded.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I found the solution by using play.tailwindcss.com:

This is the syntax I have to use in the tailwind.config.js file:

```js
module.exports = {
  purge: [],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  variants: {
    opacity: ({ after }) => after(['disabled'])
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

Comment: May I know what is this `after()` function doing? Couldn't find any documentation on this

Comment: Found the link.. https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/issues/2661#issuecomment-715498692

Comment: How do you add more variants after using the "after" syntax? Like, if I wanted opacity to  support both "active" and "disabled" how would I do that?

Comment: How to disable hover when the button is disabled?

Comment: @lAaravl you can used ```enabled``` when you only want to apply another style when an element is not disabled ```enabled:hover:border-gray-400 disabled:opacity-75```

Answer (score 5):

I had this problem and updating Tailwind CSS to the latest version fixed it.

```
npm install tailwindcss@latest postcss@latest autoprefixer@latest
```

Here's the link: [Upgrade Guide -Tailwind CSS](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/upgrading-to-v2) It will change other things that you might want to be aware of.

Comment: this is correct, it now works as documented in https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states

Comment: note the CDN version doesn't enable it; must be enabled through the tailwind config

Answer (score 3):

For me it was because I was trying to use `disabled` on a `<div>` element.

Changing the element to `<button>` resolved the issue.

Comment: Lmao, literally same. Idiot me ‍♂️

Answer (score 2):

It's now possible to enable all variants by default with the new just in time (JIT) compiler. No need to update your Tailwind config file every time you want to add a new variant.

**1. Upgrade to TailwindCSS 2.1 or later**

```
npm i -D tailwindcss@latest
```

**2. Enable JIT mode in your config**

```js
// tailwind.config.js
module.exports = {
 mode: 'jit',
  purge: [
    // ...
  ],
  theme: {
    // ...
  }
  // ...
}
```

**3. Explicitely set all files in the purge config**

The JIT compiler will look at all these files (and only these files) to generate the CSS on demand. If a file isn't listed here, the CSS won't be generated.

```js
module.exports = {
  mode: 'jit',
 // These paths are just examples, customize them to match your project structure
 purge: [
   './public/**/*.html',
   './src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,vue}',
 ],
  theme: {
    // ...
  }
  // ...
}
```

Docs: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/just-in-time-mode

Comment: JIT mode is the default in TailwindCSS v3, the current version. See https://tailwindcss.com/docs/upgrade-guide#migrating-to-the-jit-engine