# Why isn't the "disabled:" tailwind prefix working in my react app?

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I am trying to disable a submit button on some condition but it doesn't work. When I inspect the element in the browser, this is what is rendered regardless of whether the condition returns true or false.

*Element as rendered in browser*

```html
<button type="submit" disabled="" class="bg-yellow-500 text-white mt-4 disabled:bg-yellow-300 px-3 py-2 rounded-md">Submit</button>
```

*Code*

```js
state = {
        formIsVaild: false
    }

render() {
    <button type="submit" disabled={!this.state.formIsVaild} className="bg-yellow-500 text-white mt-4 disabled:bg-yellow-300 px-3 py-2 rounded-md">Open Discussion</button>
}
```

*I even removed the condition and tried this...*

```js
state = {
        formIsVaild: false
    }

render() {
    <button type="submit" disabled className="bg-yellow-500 text-white mt-4 disabled:bg-yellow-300 px-3 py-2 rounded-md">Open Discussion</button>
}
```

No matter what value I pass to the disable attribute, `disabled=""` get's rendered in the HTML. I even tried to use an input with type submit instead of a button and I'm getting the same result. I am not sure what is going on here... any help?

**Minimal example**

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class FormData extends Component {
    state = {
        formIsVaild: false
    }

    render() {
        return (
                <div className="grid grid-cols-3 gap-4">
                    <div className="col-span-2">
                        <form>
                            <button type="submit" disabled={!this.state.formIsVaild} className="bg-yellow-500 text-white mt-4 disabled:bg-yellow-300 px-3 py-2 rounded-md">Submit</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
        )
    }
}

export default FormData
```

Comment: I have updated the question to include a simple example

Comment: From your example, `formIsValid` will always be false, which will always set disabled to true.

Comment: exactly. but the button is not getting disabled.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The button is in fact disabled, but the style for the [`disabled:` tailwind prefix](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states#disabled) is not applied because it is probably not enabled, since it's *disabled* by default.

> You can control whether `disabled` variants are enabled for a plugin in
> the variants section of your `tailwind.config.js` file:
>
> ```
> // tailwind.config.js
> module.exports = {
>   // ...
>   variants: {
>     extend: {
>       opacity: ['disabled'],
>     }
>   },
> }
> ```

In your case, it would probably be `backgroundColor: ['disabled']`. ([Tailwind playground](https://play.tailwindcss.com/VmND7SYSwP))

Comment: Another answer about this: [TailwindCSS: disabled variant not working](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64962149/1218980)

Answer (score -4):

Here is a simple script I've done with React.useState()

```js
import React from 'react'


export default function App() {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState(false);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={()=>{setState(!state)}}>
        State is: {state? 'true':'false'}
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

You did not provide enough info on how You change `disable` state. I assume You miss exactly this part.

Here is with class states:
Short description: First button changes `this.state.formIsValid`,
second button is being disabled.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class FormData extends Component {
    state = {
        formIsVaild: false
    }

    render() {
        return (
          <div className="grid grid-cols-3 gap-4">
              <div className="col-span-2">
                <button onClick={()=>{this.setState({formIsVaild:!this.state.formIsVaild})}}>Change state</button>
                  <form>
                      <button type="submit" disabled={this.state.formIsVaild} className="bg-yellow-500 text-white mt-4 disabled:bg-yellow-300 px-3 py-2 rounded-md">Submit</button>
                  </form>
              </div>
          </div>
        )
    }
}
```