# disabled: prefix from typescript is not working while styling buttons in Angular app

Tags: angular, sass, tailwind-css

I have a template in an Angular app with a button that looks like this:

```html
      <button 
        type="submit"
        (click)="action()"
        class="button"
        [disabled]="isApiCallInProgress">
        Perform Action
      </button>
```

The button class has definitions for `enabled:` and `disabled:` similar to the follows:

```css
// scss
&.button {
    @apply
    // sample classes
      enabled:hover:bg-violet-600
      disabled:bg-red-400;
    }
```

However, the styling under `disabled` isn't applied when the button is disabled.

So far, I found this - the proposed solution here does not suit my app configuration:
[Why isn't the "disabled:" tailwind prefix working in my react app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66248979/why-isnt-the-disabled-tailwind-prefix-working-in-my-react-app)

Please help in determining what is causing the `disabled` styling to break.